# Available Placeholders in Visual Studio 2010/2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, placeholder, class-template

In Visual Studio we can use pre defined place holders in many places,
as an examples, 
if we are creating post build event some place holders are available to get project informations.
if we are looking at the class template, there are some place holders to take project specific things

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)using System.Linq;
$endif$using System.Text;
$if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.5)using System.Threading.Tasks;
$endif$
namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    class $safeitemrootname$
    {
    }
}
```

May be this place holders are different from place to place ( post/pre build event commands, class template etc.. )

**Is there a source where I can find all the list of available place holders?**